# How to save checkbox state even after app is closed

Tags: java, android

Hello can anyone please help on how to save my checkbox state, when i leave the Activity, refresh or close the app my ckeckbox resets to unchecked. I have try to search around but i unable to make it save, below is my code

```
    package com.example.android.xb;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class RemindersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();

    private TextView timePicker;


    private int pHour;
    private int pMinute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

                    pHour = hourOfDay;
                    pMinute = minute;
                    updateDisplay();

                }
            };

    private void updateDisplay() {
        timePicker.setText(new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(pHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(pMinute)));
    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);


        // Display for up button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Setting up the onlick listener
        findViewById(R.id.checkbox_alert).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {


                    // Time setup for notification to pop up
                    calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, pHour);
                    calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, pMinute);

                    // Setting up the notification on checkbox checked
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100,
                            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(),
                            alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);


                }
            }


        });

        // Setting up the onclick listener for time textView
        timePicker = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_set);

        timePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        pHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        pMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        updateDisplay();

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute, false);

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what SharedPreferences are for. They're written to the filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shared preferences for this:

To write data to shared preferences use for example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checkbox", checkbox.isChecked())); //first value -preference name, secend value -preference value
editor.commit();
```

To read from shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isMyValueChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox", false);//first value -preference name, secend value - default value if checbox not found
```

Comment: Can you please explain more or show me how to add it to my code I can't seem to make it work...thanks

Comment: This should work: 
In create method after setContentView: 

`final SharedPreferences sharedPref = RemindersActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
boolean isMyValueChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox", false); 
CheckBox checbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_alert); 
checbox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);`

in checkbox_alert.setOnClickListener: 

`SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit(); 
editor.putBoolean("checkbox", ((CheckBox) view).isChecked()); 
editor.commit();` On create loading value from preferences, on click saving actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see my complete Java coding for this issue:
    In onCreate Method() put these codes and your problem will get solved. My activity here is called SettingsActivity.

```
    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = SettingsActivity.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean isMyValueChecked = sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox", false);

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk_box_music);
    checkBox.setChecked(isMyValueChecked);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox", ((CheckBox) view).isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                startService(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }else{
                stopService(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MyService.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the results in SharedPreferences every time they are updated. It will be stored there even if your app is killed. You could check for the values from SharedPreferences each time you start the activity again and set the checks accordingly.

Setting up the SharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Updating or editing sharedPreferences, you may add this to whenever you update the check buttons or during your onClick:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checkBox1", true);
editor.commit();
```

You may read from sharedPreference:

```
Boolean defaultValue = sharedPref.getBoolean("checkBox1", defaultValue);
```

You can also look at the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference) or this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SharedPreferences as Micha, skbrhmn and Sabriael advise you to do. Follow the guide in the link below to help you how to do it.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

more details about SharedPreferences interface...

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html